# How to find a file in the Xcode navigator

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm looking for the location of a file in my Xcode navigator. I know where the actual file is in my directory, but not what group it has been added to in the Xcode group structure. In other words, I can't find the reference to it in the navigator. How can I find it?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enter the files name in the bottom bar (search field) of the Project Navigator (on the left side), press enter => there it is ;-)

[image]

Comment: just added an image ;-)
You can also search inside all or specific the files, using the third icon on the top (Search Navigator) :-)

Answer (score 10):

Optionally, <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> is the shortcut to access 'Filter Bar' to search files in the files navigator.